# How to pass prompt answer to servlet. JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I would like to pass a value from a prompt dialog box to servlet for validation.

HTML/JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getValue(){
   var retVal = prompt("Enter number of children:", "1");

   document.form1.someField.value = retVal;
  }
</script>
```

Servlet:

```
String something = request.getParameter("retVal1");
/*Validation code*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass values from browser to server You need to make an HTTP call.

In your javascript code You can for example force the submit of form1.

```
document.form1.submit();
```

If you need only to validate a single field without submitting the whole form you can make an ajax call.

For example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yoururl", 
    type: 'GET',                // or POST
    data: {retVal1: retVal},
    success: function(result) {

        // Handle the answer
    }
});
```